Difference between "on the canal or street or trail" and "in the canal or street or trail"?
My previous post was asking the meaning of canal in "biking on trails and canals".
Are "on the canal" and "in the canal" both used? Is their difference just like that between "on the street" and "in the street"? Do "on the canal" and "on the street" mean on the side of the canal/street? Do "in the canal" and "in the street" mean on the surface of the canal or street? Is the difference between "on" and "in" that the level of the surface of a canal or street is always lower than the level of the sidewalk?
Is there no "in the trail" but only "on the trail"? Is it because the surface of a trail is always no lower than the surface on its both sides?

No, "in the canal" is where you find the dead body floating in a police procedural.   It would be analogous to "in the pond" or "in the river".    We use "on" to refer to the surface of water:  "There were shells racing on the river."

@TimR - My mother's father, born 1890 approx, was a horse-trader in the inner part of south London. Up to around 1940 he had agreements with the various boroughs to recover dead people animals, etc, from the canals. There were ascending levels of fee for dogs, people, and horses. Some boroughs paid more than others. Family lore has it that if something needed recovery in a location near a boundary with a higher-paying borough, he would propel it along with his pole until it became eligible for the higher fee. Any attending police quite understood, especially if he split the extra with them.

We don't say that someone is in the trail, but it's nothing to do with the surface level. In the street often implies 'in an urban environment', and (at least in British English) a house in X Street means 'among the buildings along X Street'.

@MichaelHarvey I used to watch a TV show about narrowboats in England when we had access to British TV shows through one of our subscriptions.  I imagine fishing dead creatures from the canals was lucrative business back before street-lamps.

@TimR - ah yes. Those were probably pretty canals in the country; these would have been grim urban ones with cranes, gasworks, steel bridges, etc.

On the canal generally means in a boat or barge. In some contexts it means next to the canal, and that is what I would understand by "biking on the canal" - at least in the UK (and I guess elsewhere) canals almost always have a path running along next to them, the "towpath". It could also be used for a building next to the canal.
In the canal means swimming, or in the water for some other reason.
On the street and in the street are for many purposes interchangeable. There are some subtle differences, but I'm finding it difficult to characterise these.
